# Как применить новые настройки в scss файле?

Tags: css, scss

Пытаюсь добавить в файл настройку `@media`. Вот как это выглядит в исходном файле:

**SCSS**:

```css
#blog_banner {
  padding: 75px 0 0;
  background-color: #faf8f8 !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  .overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .bread_crumbs {
    line-height: 134px;
    .breadcrumb {
      background-color: transparent;
      border-radius: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding: 0 !important;
      li {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 20px;
        &:before {
          content: '/';
          color: $white;
        }
        &:first-child {
          &:before {
            display: none
          }
        }
        a {
          &:hover {
            color: $white !important;
          }
        }
      }
      .active {
        color: $white;
      }
    }
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .breadcrumb {
      margin-top: 100px;
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="blog_banner" style="background: url(images/blog/banner-bg.jpg);">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
        <!--=== Bread Crumbs ===-->
        <div class="bread_crumbs">
          <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li>
              <a href="categories.php">
                    Web Design
                  </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="categories.php">
                    Web Developing
                  </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="categories.php">
                    New
                  </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="categories.php">
                    Marketing
                  </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="categories.php">
                    Security
                  </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--=== End Bread Crumbs ===-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

То есть мне нужно что бы при определенном размере окна применялся `margin`. Но почему то, когда я захожу в настройки разработчика через браузера добавленного мной кода-нет(и на странице соответственно тоже ничего не меняется, см.скрин).

[image: Скрин с настроек браузера]

Если я перехожу с браузера в файл то там написанный мной код есть. подскажите пожалуйста что это. Никогда раньше не работал с `scss`, буду признателен.

Comment: Как вы компилируете SASS в CSS? Имею ввиду, что используете для этого?

Comment: @VladSpirin http://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно повторить ту же цепочку, что и выше:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  #blog_banner {
    .bread_crumbs {
      .breadcrumb {
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1. `#blog_banner .bread_crumbs .breadcrumb` приоритетнее, чем `#blog_banner .breadcrumb`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.breadcrumb {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .breadcrumb {
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
}
```

Comment: ничего не произошло, в браузере эти настройки тоже не отобразились

Comment: html-код покажите

Comment: Добавил в вопрос